# Plot x-axis with string array as in the same order in original array and not sort it alphabetically in matplotlib

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Either Numpy or Matplotlib is changing the order of my np.array and it's conflicting with my plot. It's causing the months to be out of order while the corresponding data to still be in the same order which is causing the plot to look weird:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

f = np.array([53, 56, 63, 72, 79, 86, 89, 88, 83, 74, 65, 56])
month = np.array(["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"])
plt.plot(month, f)

plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabel('Temperature')
plt.title('Average Monthly Temperature in Elizabeth City, NC')
plt.show()
```

This is what i get as output in JupyterNotebook:
[image]

Comment: Matplotlib is sorting it alphabetically before plotting it

Comment: Oh okay. It's weird that its still using the corresponding data in the right order.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say is: matplotlib is turning the strings into x-coordinates by ordering all the strings, and returning the position of each one. The order of the line is unchanged, and still passes through the months in order

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `month` is a string array, `plt.plot()` command is sorting it alphabetically. So, we have to use the `xticks` and then plot it like below to get the strings in the same order as it were in the original array `month`.

```
In [16]: f = np.array([53, 56, 63, 72, 79, 86, 89, 88, 83, 74, 65, 56])
    ...: month = np.array(["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"])
    ...: plt.xticks(range(len(f)), month)
    ...: plt.plot(f)
```

Plot:

[image: plt with months in alphabetical order]

Note: For more customized plots refer: [pylab date demo](https://matplotlib.org/1.5.3/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo2.html)

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I truly appreciate it :)

Comment: Note that this won't make the month of january wider than february to reflect its extra days, unlike @AGN's solution below

Comment: @Eric I've added a note at the bottom!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `MonthLocator` and `set_major_locator` as shown here: [formatting timeseries x-axis in pandas/matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702486/formatting-timeseries-x-axis-in-pandas-matplotlib)

Here is my attempt:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import datetime
f = np.array([53, 56, 63, 72, 79, 86, 89, 88, 83, 74, 65, 56])
```

---

```
# New stuff:
from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator, DateFormatter
dates = []
for month in range(1, 13):
    dates.append(datetime.datetime(year=2018, month=month, day=1))
plt.plot(dates, f)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlim([dates[0], dates[-1]])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%b'))
```

---

```
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabel('Temperature')
plt.title('Average Monthly Temperature in Elizabeth City, NC')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Im having trouble trying to implement those with my existing code

Comment: @EdselNorwood I have added an example to my answer. Check it out.

Comment: Once you have an `ax` object, you may as well call all the `plt` methods on it too - `ax.xlabel`, `ax.ylabel`, and `ax.title`