# Plotting sorted values

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Assume an unsorted array. What would be the best way to plot the values of the array in a sorted order with vertical labels corresponding to the magnitude and the horizontal labels being the index of the value in the original unsorted array?

Comment: Are you aware of numpy.sort and numpy.argsort? What did you try that didn't work out?

Comment: You may get some hints on sorting data from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37414916/pythons-matplotlib-plotting-in-wrong-order), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647875/how-to-prevent-alphabetical-sorting-for-python-bars-with-matplotlib) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413069/plot-x-axis-with-string-array-as-in-the-same-order-in-original-array-and-not-sor)