# Pandas / matplotlib is showing 2018 and 2019 years as 48 and 49

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am using Pandas to plot a dataframe with two time series in a single chart. However, the year information is coming out with strange numbers. The years 2018 and 2019 are coming out as 48 and 49, respectively, on the x-axis. For example, the date 05-01-2018 becomes 05-01-48. See the figure at the bottom of this question.

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702486/formatting-timeseries-x-axis-in-pandas-matplotlib), but the solution to that problem says to use matplotlib's `plot()` rather than Pandas' `df.plot()` function. I would prefer to use `df.plot()` because it can easily plot two time series together.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator, DateFormatter

indx = pd.date_range('2017-04-01', '2019-01-01')
seriesA = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(indx)), index=indx)
seriesB = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(indx)), index=indx)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': seriesA, 'b': seriesB})

df.head()
#                    a         b
# 2017-04-01 -1.191265 -0.268962
# 2017-04-02  1.545406 -0.805481
# 2017-04-03  0.022768 -1.412308
# 2017-04-04 -2.024388  0.268758
# 2017-04-05  0.900840 -1.654095

ax = df.plot(y=['a', 'b'], figsize=(12,7))

xtick_locator = MonthLocator(interval=1)
xtick_dateformatter = DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(xtick_locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xtick_dateformatter)
ax.autoscale_view()
_ = plt.xticks(rotation=90, )
_ = plt.grid()
_ = plt.xlabel('')
_ = plt.ylim(0)

_ = plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Just going to go out on a limb and guess it's the DateFormatter, what happens if you just format the index from the start like this `indx = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2017-04-01', '2019-01-01')).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')`?

Comment: @chet-the-wizard: That line is returning the correct result: 04/01/2017, 04/02/2017, etc.

Comment: I was saying that if you use a string for the index from the start instead of a DateTime object then you won't have to use the DateFormatter object which is probably responsible for the formatting error.  Could at least help debug.

Comment: @chet-the-wizard: I need the date column as a DateTime in order to plot with the date on the x-axis. The only problem is the year portion of the date.

Comment: Likely, 48 and 49 means 2018 and 2019 are the 48th and 49th year since epoch (1970-01-01), the international unix start time standard.

Comment: Seems more fit for a github issue than a SO question. For me this is clearly a matplotlib bug : unintended behavior, easily reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `plt.FixedFormatter` taking monthly dates from a pandas `resample`. Belows uses posted data that begins in 2017.

```
# RESAMPLE SERIES (TAKING INDEX VALUES)
x_dates = pd.Series(df.resample('MS').max().index).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
# ASSIGN AS AXIS TICKS
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FixedFormatter(x_dates))
ax.set_xticklabels(labels=x_dates, rotation=45, ha='center')

xtick_locator = MonthLocator(interval=1)    
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(xtick_locator)

plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True)

ax.autoscale_view()
_ = plt.xticks(rotation=90, ha='center')
_ = plt.grid()
_ = plt.xlabel('')
_ = plt.ylim(0)
_ = plt.show()
```

[image: Time Series Plot Output]